# Tensorflow installation fails on PowerPC ppc64le

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, powerpc, rhel7

I am trying to install tensorflow on Rhel 7.6 ppc64le. I have Python 3.6.3 installed.

ERROR:

```
pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Would like some help on this issue.
Environment: Rhel 7.6 - ppc64le
python :3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because it cannot find anything on pypi that is suitable for your setup. If you check the [tensorflow pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files), you will see that only wheel files are available and only for either x86 or x64 based systems. For ppc64le there are none.

You have some options though:

1. Build from source, see [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)
2. Use miniconda, as there is a conda package for `tensorflow` in the default channels that supports your architecture

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install TensorFlow using Anaconda which sometimes has build able to install TensorFlow on older CPUs.

```
> conda create -n tf_env tensorflow=2
```